# Getting variable from another namespace not working

Tags: c#, string, class, variables

I'm trying to get a variable `(string)` from another namespace. I tried many possibilities, but none of them succeed.

```
namespace CPLoader
{
    public class dbC
    {
        public string _CS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I `MessageBox` "_CS", it's always empty. I have no errors, a reference to `CPLoader` is set...

I set it's value like so:

```
namespace CP
{
    public class dbMain
    {
        private void MyMethod()
        {
            ... do work ...
            CPLoader.dbC._CS = Mystring;
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't this working ?

Comment: To use `CPLoader.dbC._CS` as in your example, the property should be marked as `static` - alternatively you should create an instance of `dbC` eg, `var myDbc = new dbC();`

Comment: I also tried that possibility.. Not working, it's always empty.

Comment: Indeed, your code as written will not compile, so perhaps you should include a more complete example. The code you've posted would give a compiler error message that you require an instance of `dbC` to access the non-static property `_CS`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, variables don't live in a namespace alone, they live inside another class that could be in another namespace.  If you need to access a variable in another class (in another namespace), your other class needs to expose the variable somehow.  The common practice for this is to use a public Property (static if you only need access to that variable) for the variable.

```
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class MyClassA
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            // Use value from MyOtherClass
            int myValue = My.Some.Namespace.MyClassB.MyInt;
        }
    }
}

namespace My.Some.Namespace
{
    public class MyClassB
    {
        private static int myInt;
        public static int MyInt
        {
            get {return myInt;}
            set {myInt = value;}
        }

        // Can also do this in C#3.0
        public static int MyOtherInt {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you want to access the variable you need to make it static.

```
namespace CPLoader
{
    public class dbC
    {
        public static string _CS { get; set; }
    }
}
```